# How to extract DEM files from google Earth/Map for surfer?

Tags: google-maps, dem, google-earth, surfer

I will need to do a 3D representation of a terrain and I heard surfer is ideal, but then I do not have a DEM file of the region, I know Google Earth and Map could help, but I do not know how? If there is another way round, please where can I get one for free?

Comment: If you are just looking for a free DEM you can use SRTM 1arc second (~30m) available through NASAs [EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/)

Comment: @Kersten This really should be the answer. I wish I could up-vote your comment twice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use TCX converter for generating DEM from google earth.
Check this [Contours and DEM from Google Earth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=237pVwC3fNk)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArcGIS with ArcGoogle tool to download DEM from Google Earth and create contours from DEM

Here's clip for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKZ4gJokg7o